# Two-column bibliography in one-column document

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, koma-script, biber, two-column

I'd like to have a two-column bibliography in a one-column `scrartcl`. I'm using [`BibLaTeX`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex?lang=en) with backend [`biber`](http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net). To obtain a two-column table of contents where the header doesn't "fall" into the columns, I use the [koma-script](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script?lang=en) commands

```
\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\end{multicols}}
```

Is there something similar for the bibliography in [`BibLaTeX`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex?lang=en)? Right now I'm using

```
\begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{References}]
    \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{multicols}
```

It looks fine but it's not very semantic.

Comment: [Obligatory PhD Comic](http://phdcomics.com/comics.php?f=1692)

Comment: Perhaps this is a better solution: [biblatex/multicol: Incorrect vertical space after bibliography heading](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/22078)

Comment: Did the answer linked in Alan's comment solve your issue? Or do you want something else? In that case it would really help if you could edit your question and clarify what you find lacking.

Comment: @moewe egreg's answer linked to by Alan recommends exactly the solution I presented in my question, except he packages it into its own command which isn't that useful for something that's usually only needed once per document. So I guess you could call my issue solved if the answer is, no there is no better built-in way to do this.

Comment: There is no built-in way to get a two-column bibliography in a single-column document. egreg's answer seems to be the most elegant solution (I had a look yesterday and could not find something better with `\defbibenvironment` or the like.) Of course you don't have to use a command, if you don't want to. I'm voting to close as a duplicate then, if that's all right with you.

Comment: @moewe Sure, go ahead.